# Can I password protect my Task Scheduler? if yes Can I import that Password to my Python Script?

Tags: python, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I have developed a Script which is automating some manual efforts using the UI.

- What the Script do? >> After running the script it will navigate to a website, and there I have to give my Admin User Name and Password.
- What I want to do >> To schedule this task, and whenever I run it, it will ask for "User Name" and "Password", which will be fed to the Admin username and Login parameters.

Can it be done? If yes How? What is the process?

Comment: "Can it be done?" is a really poor question to ask. The answer is usually "Yes", which you won't find helpful. You should rephrase your question to get answers that you find useful.

Comment: @BobDalgleish , I have edited it, can you tell me how it can be done?